# What is better to use with JPA FetchType.LAZY @Transactional or @NamedEntityGraph

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I used Spring Boots @Transactional on the Service Layer to avoid the Lazyinitializationexception. But is there an advantage of using @NamedEntityGraph instead of @Transactional to avoid Lazyinitializationexception?

Comment: An honest answer is going to be depends. What are you using from the data - if you are fetching a list from a complicated object graph and then looking at one or two elements from it, and one or two leafs from the graphs, using a generic NamedEntityGraph to fetch the entire object graph structure for each element in the list might be a lot of overhead. Sure, it'll be one query maybe, but less statements/queries to the DB isn't always better when you factor in costs in processing the data back to build the entities to return. You have to evaluate each use case individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@NamedEntityGraph not only avoid Lazyinitializationexception but also helps optimizing the number of requests sent to avoid N+1 effect. This may be a valuable advantage but needs more work to ensure that every needed object will be fetched before the end of the hibernate session.